# SQL Server 2008 installation (not working)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008, but have been unable to do so. I've tried uninstalling and even manual un-installation.

I've tried following this guide http://www.intellitechture.com/sql-server-2008-install-nightmare/ but I just can't figure out this error. If anyone has any ideas how to fix this they would be very welcome. Thanks.

I'm using windows 7 and I'm logged in as a normal administrator user.

```
2010-11-07 11:17:58 SQLBrowser: sRegLocation = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server', regView = 'ProcessDefault', sSddl = '(A;CI;KR;;;[SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DANIEL-PC])', bOptional = 'False'.
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid in security descriptor (A;CI;KR;;;[SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DANIEL-PC])
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be processed:  (A;CI;KR;;;[SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DANIEL-PC])
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Account name to be translated into SID: SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DANIEL-PC
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DANIEL-PC
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DANIEL-PC
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: GetSidForAccount normalized accountName SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DANIEL-PC parameter to SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DANIEL-PC
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Account name is translated into: S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Final security descriptor:  (A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to set security descriptor (A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize security descriptor (A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Adding 'D:' DACL identifier to the input security descriptor (A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid in security descriptor D:(A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be processed:  D:(A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be returned:  D:(A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize security descriptor D:(A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid in security descriptor D:(A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be processed:  D:(A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be returned:  D:(A;CI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-3917135324-3775861390-1902975589-1031)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Prompting user if they want to retry this action due to the following failure:
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: ----------------------------------------
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: 
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:     Message: 
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:         Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:     Data: 
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:       WatsonData = Microsoft SQL Server
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:       DisableRetry = true
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:     Inner exception type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:         Message: 
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:                 Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:         Stack: 
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:                 at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.GetSecurityInfo(ResourceType resourceType, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections accessControlSections, RawSecurityDescriptor& resultSd)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:                 at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistrySecurity..ctor(ResourceType resourceType, SafeRegistryHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistrySecurity.Create(InternalRegistryKey key)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.GetAccessControl()
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.SetSecurityDescriptor(String sddl, Boolean overwrite)
2010-11-07 11:17:58 Slp: ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you using an administrative account to do the install?

Comment: Yes i am, I've also tried turning UAC off.

Comment: Do you have visual studio installed?

Comment: It could be conflicting with Visual Studio. On the other hand, it looks like there might be an issue creating the SQL service accounts, which is possible if you didn't remove these during your manual removal.

Comment: How would you go about removing these service accounts then?

Comment: And yes I have visual studio installed.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like some permission issue `System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.GetSecurityInfo`. You said you are logged in as a normal administrator (what do you mean by the same?). When you hit setup.exe it should prompt for elevated permission and then the installation will proceed.

Comment: Yeah, it did that.
If it was that easy I wouldn't be here.

Comment: I would run Process Monitor when running the setup and check for ACCESS DENIED or FAILURE?